# Changing the generated CRS to WGS84 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile from the county tax authority that defines land parcel boundaries and want to use it to plan hikes that stay on public property.  However the file loads in QGIS with a generated CRS.  How do I get the file to work accurately in QGIS with my kml and gpx tracks?

Comment: What projection are your tracks and kml in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `On-the-fly-reprojection` is activated (and it will if you add any layer with a different CRS) all layers should align.

You can use `Save As ...` to a different filename and CRS EPSG:4326 to make sure the county data is in WGS84.